# How to check the status of a link?

Tags: network-programming, tcl, ns2, wireless

I'm running a MANET simulation in ns2 using AODV routing protocol. Is there any way I can check whether a node forwards data it receives to the next node in the route or check whether the link between 2 nodes is active?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package require http
package require tls
http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -tls1 1]
set url "https://google.com"
if {![catch {set token [::http::geturl $url]} msg]} {
    if {[::http::status $token] == "ok"} {
        #Do something when token is ok for example print HTTTP code
        puts [::http::code $token]
    } else {
        #Do something when status token is not ok
    }
} else {
    #print error when Url is invalid or host is unreachable
     puts "oops: $msg"
}
```

Comment: That's completely irrelevant to the question, which is about testing routing in a network simulator, not talking HTTPS to google. Did you mean to post this as an answer to a different question?